# Get the indexes of selected rows in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rows, selected

I want get the rows I selected from gridview use a checkbox.
The checkbox is like this!
`<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                                    oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>`
And I want to get one column in each row.
How to do it.thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)checkbox.NamingContainer;
    if (checkbox.Checked == true) {
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        mygridview.Columns(0).Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For people trying this; add this : using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the GridView rows and use FindControl to retrieve the Checkbox and then get the IsChecked property on them.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
  CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckboxID");

  if (CheckBox1.Checked)
  {
   ...
  } 
}
```