# ASP Listview - checkbox event findcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listview

I'm trying to build a Listview EDIT/Insert template where I can use a checkbox to enable updating multiple database tables but to little success.. I managed to get the insert working by performing some foul sorcery on the Listview inserting event. But I'd prefer that it works with the Checkbox OnCheckedChanged event as it feels abit more kosher in my mind, and of course the added benefit on it working for the edittemplate..

```
    protected void checktest_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //testlabel.Text = testcheck.Checked.ToString(); <-- exists outside of LW
        //                                                   so it works
        //Label hejha = (Label)lwRapport.FindControl("testlabel");
        CheckBox trial = (CheckBox)lwRapport.FindControl("upParameter");

        if(trial != null)
        {
            if(trial.Checked == true)
            { testlabel.Text = "finally"; }

            if(trial.Checked == false)
            { testlabel.Text = "Nope, not going to happen"; }
        }
        if (trial == null)
        { testlabel.Text = "not wanted"; }
    }
```

That's my test snippet for checking how the FindControl works and so far I've been quite unsuccessful making it do what I want it to do.. 
Any Correction on faults / hack / workaround for this matter would be apritiated

EDIT1*
The checkbox is inside of the listview, more precisely in the inserttemplate. The template looks something on the lines like this:

```
    textbox  <bind"table1.element">
    textbox2 <bind"table1.element2">
    checkbox [_]
    textbox3 <bind"table2.element">
```

Observe that the snippet above is just a pseudocode snippet of my layout not the acctual layout. What I'm attempting is to find the checkbox and bind it's checked value to a parameter which passes a couple of checks in the SPROC then executes the UPDATE command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be not able to find the check box control from the list view. This is because you are searching for the check box inside the list view, and what you should be doing is searching for it inside the selected item.

Comment: well that's because the checkbox is inside of the listview, I'll edit and add an example on what the template looks like

Comment: i haven't used insertTemplates, but if it is like the item template you have to find the control from the item, and not from the list view (somehing like item.FindControl("upParameter") where item is your current selected ListViewDataItem

Comment: or maybe try the lwRapport.InsertItem.FindControl("upParameter")

Comment: Yup know, that's my "foul sorcery" but the edittemplate is not an Item template so I can't repeat the process for that one. Thanks again for your continued attempts

Comment: I finally managed to solve it, I just had to create a more specific findcontrol parameter, it was embarissingly easy, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593577/get-the-indexes-of-selected-rows-in-gridview). Although it's GridView, I think it will works too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll give it a shot, but due to the different nature of the Listview I doubt it'll work